# Unable to find a specification for '[Any pod libraries]'

Tags: cocoapods

I don't know what's wrong with my cocoapods. It always show this error on every pod libraries every time I run pod install. For instance "AFNetworking"

```
[!] Unable to find a specification for `AFNetworking (~> 3.0)`
```

I tried the following but nothing help:

```
pod repo update
sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
pod setup
pod install
```

I tried to update my cocoapods to 1.1.1, Xcode to 8.2 and Mac OS to 10.12.2 but problem remain.

My cocoapods can't even search. It show this error every time I run "pod search AFNetworking"

```
[!] Unable to find a pod with name, author, summary, or description matching `AFNetworking`
```

Here is my podfile look like:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Leader' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
end
```

I did try to uninstall and reinstall cocoapods back but nothing help.

Comment: I have the same issue, have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

## Please follow below format in your pod file its working in project.

#Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '8.0'
 #Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
 use_frameworks!

target 'applicationName' do

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'

end

## If you find any issue please let me know.

Comment: [!] Unable to find a specification for `AFNetworking (~> 3.0)`

Comment: remove the cocoapods directory "rm -rf ~/.cocoapods" and try to "pod setup" again.hope so your issue will resolved.actually its working fine from my end.

Comment: # sudo rm -rf ~/.cocoapods && pod setup && pod install

Comment: I tries all of those, but it still couldn't help